# Long shot: Can Adobe AIR get the current url of your firefox tab?

Tags: air

I know this is a longshot but I was wondering if anyone knows if this is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Most browsers set the [HTTP_REFERRER](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referer) header to the current URL when requesting a linked document.  However, it can be spoofed so don't use it for security.

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing about air.

But if AIR has JavaScript access, and you can access the container document ( [How do I share a javascript object between different pages in Adobe AIR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193130/how-do-i-share-a-javascript-object-between-different-pages-in-adobe-air) ) then all you need to work out is how to obtain Document.location from it.

Answer (score 0):

I reckon this is rather late, but since I was searching for the same information 3 years later, here it goes.

[LoaderInfo.loaderUrl](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/LoaderInfo.html#loaderURL) should give you the information you are after.

HTH!